# will bring the subview to the front?

Tags: cocoa, calayer

i have this little cocoa snippet

```
[subView setWantsLayer:YES];
```

thus,the subView covers all the other subview suppose to be on top of it.How to put it to the back as it should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layer-backed views render on top of regular views, so the only way you can do this is to make the other views layer-backed too

Comment: The problem is when i set all the views layer-backed,the font in  NSTextView with transparent background will be blurred.